# python call function in get method of dictionary instead default value

Tags: python, dictionary

Need some help in order to understand some things in Python and `get` dictionary method.

Let's suppose that we have some list of dictionaries and we need to make some data transformation (e.g. get all names from all dictionaries by key `'name'`). Also I what to call some specific function `func(data)` if key `'name'` was not found in specific dict.

```
def func(data):
    # do smth with data that doesn't contain 'name' key in dict
    return some_data

def retrieve_data(value):
    return ', '.join([v.get('name', func(v)) for v in value])
```

This approach works rather well, but as far a I can see function `func` (from `retrieve_data`) **call each time**, even key `'name'` is present in dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling `func` if the dictionary contains the value, you can use this:

```
def retrieve_data(value):
    return ', '.join([v['name'] if 'name' in v else func(v) for v in value])
```

The reason `func` is called each time in your example is because it gets evaluated before `get` even gets called.